# Domain model object to access another domain model object

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Service has dal and domain model layers.  Domain model has access to dal for manipulating db through it.  Now a need arises to have some properties from another object within domain model (this will ease client usage significantly).  But I am confused as to where to fill those properties (from "alien") object into a given object.  Can I do it in domain model?  Or in a service itself?

Since I am new to DDD, I'll explain it in my own words.  Project has structure as:
DAL (knows about DTO)
DTO 
DomainModel (knows about DAL and DTO)
Service (knows about DomainModel and DTO)

Service returns DTOs and suppose I need to add some properties to dto1 (which is manipulated by domainModel1 class) which can be naturally retrieved by domainModel2 class.  So, the question is what layer would be most appropriate for this?

P.S.Since model is a projection of a system and that is relationships between its elements, than there is no reason from NOT calling daominModel2 from domainModel1, is there?

Comment: by alien do you mean in is in another aggregate root? if you can use DDD terms you ask some questions without showing class structure. But if not you need to show enough structure for one to know why you think the object is alien

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to DDD.  By alien I simply meant that if classA is to be modified to have some property from classB, than where should I put the logic in using classB's ability to retreive its properties and than copy some of them over to classA

Comment: do you have some use case in mind? it depends on the use case and the classes that satisfy the use case. if class B has access to the dal and also has a relationship with class A, there is no general DDD reason that logic for updating A couldn't be in B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to add some properties to dto1 (which is manipulated by
>   domainModel1 class)

The problem here seems to be that your domain objects manipulate DTO's. Your domain layer should be agnostic of DTO's and DAL.

DTO's are a detail of how a particular application needs its data presented. The DAL is a detail of how a particular application needs its data stored. These need to be separated from the domain.

Your domain shouldn't depend upon details. The details should depend on the domain.

You mention that the need to add some properties from another object to a DTO is for client usage purposes. *Therefore*, don't handle that in the domain. Create a Service in the Application layer that aggregates some data from Entity1 and Entity2 into a DTO, then passes the DTO to the client.